# Efficiently counting occurrences of a word list in a column using R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

If I have a word list, how do I efficiently count the number of occurrences of these words in a dataset?

An example:

```
set.seed(123) 
df_data <- data.frame(   
   data_strings = sample(c("tom smith", "smith jim", "sam sam", "ted", "xxx"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df_names <- data.frame(
   names = c("tom", "jim", "sam", "ted", "yyy")
)
```

That is:

```
> df_data
   data_strings
1       sam sam
2       sam sam
3     smith jim
4     smith jim
5       sam sam
6           xxx
7           ted
8     tom smith
9     smith jim
10      sam sam
```

and

```
> df_names
  names
1   tom
2   jim
3   sam
4   ted
5   yyy
```

I can do this with `str_count` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
library(tictoc)
tic()
df_data$counts <- as.vector(sapply(
  paste(df_names[,"names"], collapse='|'), 
  str_count, 
  string=df_data$data_strings
))
toc()
```

This produces the desired result:

```
> df_data
   data_strings counts
1       sam sam      2
2       sam sam      2
3     smith jim      1
4     smith jim      1
5       sam sam      2
6           xxx      0
7           ted      1
8     tom smith      1
9     smith jim      1
10      sam sam      2
```

However, since my real data contains millions of rows, and my word list is also in the millions. This turns out to be a very inefficient way yo get the result. **How can I speed it up?** I tried to utilize more cores with the `parallel` package, but it finishes in the same time (it only uses one core although I tell it to use more than one). I'm on windows so I cannot test `mclapply()`. The `parallel` seems to be working correctly, since I can get it to use more cores on other examples.

```
library(stringr)
library(parallel)
library(tictoc)

cl <- makeCluster(4, type = "PSOCK")
tic()
df_data$counts <- as.vector(parSapply(
  cl = cl,
  paste(df_names[,"names"], collapse='|'),
  FUN=str_count, 
  string=df_data$data_strings
))
toc()
stopCluster(cl)
```

What other approaches could I try? Something with data.tables? Can the paste inside the apply be done differently?

Comment: I don't understand what you are counting?

Comment: @F.Privé The number of first names (as listed in df_names) in each row

Comment: Why `sam` is 2? Because of `sam sam`?

Comment: @F.Privé Yes, that is correct

Comment: You may want to add word boundaries to your regex depending on your desired output. Right now `"sam"` in `df_names` would match for "sam" "samuel" "samual" "sammy" etc.. Unless that is ok with you. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Andrew That is a good point, I need to add that. How do I do it in this case? In a normal R regex that would be a ’\\b’ in the beginning and end, right?

Comment: You are correct! `paste0("\\b", as.character(df_names[,"names"]), "\\b", collapse='|')` should do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is faster on the real size dataset but you can use `quanteda` which has multicore support built in and should be pretty efficient in this case:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(quanteda)
quanteda_options("threads" = 4) # choose how many threads are used

df_data$counts <- df_data %>%
  pull(data_strings) %>% 
  dfm() %>%                               # construct document-feature-matrix
  dfm_keep(pattern = df_names$names) %>%  # keep features that are names
  convert(to = "data.frame") %>%          # convert to data.frame
  select(-document) %>%                   # remove non-numeric columns
  rowSums()                               # only keep sums

df_data
#>    data_strings counts
#> 1       sam sam      2
#> 2       sam sam      2
#> 3     smith jim      1
#> 4     smith jim      1
#> 5       sam sam      2
#> 6           xxx      0
#> 7           ted      1
#> 8     tom smith      1
#> 9     smith jim      1
#> 10      sam sam      2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that I set the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing the `data.frames`. Otherwise you will run into problems with factors.

I could imagine that this is faster if you have a lot of names in your set. But in my bench marking the `stringr::str_count` and `stringi::stri_count_regex` were faster with the small set of names you provided.

Comment: This looks like the type of solution I'm looking for, it's about 100 times faster on larger datasets

Comment: I had a hunch this might be the case as I tried something similar before and the time  it takes to run `str_count ` seems to increase quite a lot for every additional pattern you plug in. Eventually this will outweigh the time it takes to convert the text to a dfm. But hard to benchmark with an example.

Comment: One thing, I did not post this clearly on my question, but after some checking I see that this method doesn't handle string with spaces the way I wish it would. Using these two inputs:  

`df_data <- data.frame(   
  data_strings = c("tom", "sam", "sam tom", "xxx yyy", "aaa xxx yyy bbb")
)`

... and ... 

`df_names <- data.frame(
  names = c("tom", "jim", "sam", "xxx yyy")
)`

... I would like the `"aaa xxx yyy bbb"` to register as a `1`, also the  `"xxx yyy"` should be a `1`. Both are zero at the moment.

Comment: If the longest name consists of 2 words you can replace the `dfm()` command with `dfm(ngrams = 1:2, concatenator = " ")`. Check with `max(stringi::stri_count_fixed(df_names$names, " ")) + 1`. If the value is higher than 2 replace 2 in the `dfm()` call.

Answer (score 2):

`str_count()` is already vectorized, you don't need `sapply()`, just use `stringr::str_count(df_data$data_strings, paste(df_names$names, collapse='|'))`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, but actually, this was my first try. It was as slow as the sapply-versions I listed. Is this the reason why the parallelization doesn't work?

Comment: All {stringr} code is written in C++ if I remember correctly, it should be much faster than using `sapply()`.

Comment: Just checked, it was basically as slow, maybe marginally faster when I tested on a sample of my data real data.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the underlying `stringi::stri_count_regex`. The syntax is the same in this case and `stringr` is just a convenience package to call `stringi`. Not sure if it adds much speed but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have repeated names in `df_data`, you could use a join in `data.table` to speed things up. If you do not have a lot of repeated names I do not think it would help too much. Also, be sure to take out repeated names from you search pattern as well. Even things like `"sam"` and `"samuel"` would be repeated for partial string matching (although tricky to parse out).

```
setDT(df_data2, key = "data_strings")
dt_data2 <- unique(df_data2)

dt_data2[, counts := str_count(string = data_strings, pattern = str_c(df_names$names, collapse='|'))]
dt_data2[df_data2]

    data_strings counts
 1:      sam sam      2
 2:      sam sam      2
 3:      sam sam      2
 4:      sam sam      2
 5:    smith jim      1
 6:    smith jim      1
 7:    smith jim      1
 8:          ted      1
 9:    tom smith      1
10:          xxx      0
```

**Data**:

```
set.seed(123) 
df_data <- data.frame(   
  data_strings = sample(c("tom smith", "smith jim", "sam sam", "ted", "xxx"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df_names <- data.frame(
  names = c("tom", "jim", "sam", "ted", "yyy")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question regarding the limit of performance; so I built up a benchmark template to visually compare the performance of different methods.

***This post is made to wiki community, so everyone is welcome to add different approaches for the speed challenge.***

**Benchmark Template**

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(stringr)

set.seed(123) 
df_data <- data.frame(   
  data_strings = sample(c("tom smith", "smith jim", "sam sam", "ted", "xxx"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
)

df_names <- data.frame(
  names = c("tom", "jim", "sam", "ted", "yyy")
)

# method by Joshua
f_Joshua <- function() {as.vector(sapply(
  paste(df_names[,"names"], collapse='|'), 
  str_count, 
  string=df_data$data_strings
))}
# method by F. Privé
f_F.Prive <- function() str_count(df_data$data_strings, paste(df_names[,"names"], collapse='|'))
# method by ThomasIsCoding
f_ThomasIsCoding1 <- function() {sapply(as.vector(df_data$data_strings), function(x) sum(unlist(strsplit(x,split = " "))%in% df_names$names) )}
f_ThomasIsCoding2 <- function() {sapply(strsplit(as.vector(df_data$data_strings),split = " "), function(x) sum(x %in% df_names$names))}
f_ThomasIsCoding3 <- function() {
  bk <- paste0(df_names$names,collapse = "|")
  lengths(regmatches(df_data$data_strings,gregexpr(bk,df_data$data_strings)))
}
f_ThomasIsCoding4 <- function() {
  with(df_data, as.numeric(ave(as.vector(data_strings),as.numeric(data_strings),FUN = function(x) sum(strsplit(unique(as.vector(x)),split = " ")[[1]] %in% as.vector(df_names$names)))))
}


bm <- microbenchmark(
  f_Joshua(),
  f_F.Prive(),
  f_ThomasIsCoding1(),
  f_ThomasIsCoding2(),
  f_ThomasIsCoding3(),
  f_ThomasIsCoding4(),
  times = 10,
  check = "equivalent",
  unit = "relative")
```

such that

```
> bm
Unit: relative
                expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
          f_Joshua()  1.126535  1.067945  0.6261978  1.028165  0.9859666  0.2677307    10
         f_F.Prive()  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.0000000  1.0000000    10
 f_ThomasIsCoding1() 57.177203 61.011742 32.5759501 54.980633 53.4825275 12.4735502    10
 f_ThomasIsCoding2() 18.167507 18.053833 11.8592174 17.945895 23.3277056  4.4468403    10
 f_ThomasIsCoding3() 63.448741 72.585445 35.6459037 65.608859 61.8789544  8.8344612    10
 f_ThomasIsCoding4()  4.039085  3.994598  2.1024356  3.545432  3.3914213  0.7529932    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some base R solutions.

Since my methods are all with base R, so the performance will not be as good as using `stringr` package, but maybe you can borrow some ideas if you think they are useful.

```
# method by ThomasIsCoding
f_ThomasIsCoding1 <- function() {sapply(as.vector(df_data$data_strings), function(x) sum(unlist(strsplit(x,split = " "))%in% df_names$names) )}

f_ThomasIsCoding2 <- function() {sapply(strsplit(as.vector(df_data$data_strings),split = " "), function(x) sum(x %in% df_names$names))}

f_ThomasIsCoding3 <- function() {
  bk <- paste0(df_names$names,collapse = "|")
  lengths(regmatches(df_data$data_strings,gregexpr(bk,df_data$data_strings)))
}

f_ThomasIsCoding4 <- function() {
  with(df_data, as.numeric(ave(as.vector(data_strings),as.numeric(data_strings),FUN = function(x) sum(strsplit(unique(as.vector(x)),split = " ")[[1]] %in% as.vector(df_names$names)))))
}
```

You can see the benchmark in my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59719062/12158757)